# No puedo crear un proyecto en Java con NetBeans 12.0

Tags: java, netbeans

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de las opciones al crear un nuevo proyecto solo puedo crear un proyecto en Java with Maiven, no sale la opción de "Java" solamente, tampoco lo he encontrado dentro de los pluggins

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hace mucho que no uso NetBeans pero creo recordar que es opción fue eliminada, por lo que ahora solo puedes crear proyectos que usen algunos de los 3 sistemas de gestión de proyectos soportados: Maven, Gradle y Ant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que esto ha sido reestructurado en **Apache NetBeans 11.0** por lo que puedes encontrar lo que quieres en **java with Ant**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, si creó un proyecto usando **Archivo> Nuevo proyecto ...> Java> Aplicación Java** en versiones anteriores de NetBeans, debe usar **Archivo> Nuevo proyecto ...> Java con Ant> Aplicación Java** en NetBeans 11.0 o superior.

Comment: Ant es una herramienta parecida a Maven, por lo que esta respuesta no es lo que busca el OP.

Comment: @E.Betanzos desconozco del todo si es lo mismo, pero la construcción del proyecto es diferente, me parece que con lo que se refiere a la pregunta es que quiere construir un proyecto tal cual como se hacia en en **NetBeants 8.1**, con lo cual con **Ant** se hace similar.

Comment: Tienes razón Richard. Me tomé la molestia de descargarme una versión vieja de NetBeans (exactamete la 6.9.1) y sí, los proyectos "normales" siempre usan Ant.